# Difference between "high quality material and high quality of material"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, difference

What is the difference between"high quality material and high quality of material"?

Do they use in the same way or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where in the sentence a phrase like this would be used. When used as an object, I might say this phrase in one of two ways:

> ***I expect this jacket to last a long time, due to its high-quality material.*** (hyphen is optional)
>
> ***I expect this jacket to last a long time, due to the high quality of the material***.

When used as the subject, I would probably only use the version without the *of*:

> ***High quality material should make this jacket last a long time***.

There are plenty of valid variations with regards to surrounding articles, prepositions, etc. For example, this is another way I could say it:

> ***I expect this jacket to last a long time, thanks to a high-quality material.***